# kernel 3.7 switching to clocksource tsc freeze on startup

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, kernel

I can't start my ubuntu 12.10 with kernel 3.7, it freezes on a black screen.

When I choose advanced options and select the newest kernel it shows some lines and the last of them is "switching to clocksource tsc"

My system is a amd athlon II x4 630 with a nvidia video board.

It works fine with kernel 3.5

Comment: We can't really tell you anything until we know more about your system, but the link above might solve your problem.